# Electric Arc Furnace Steam Production

Tags: electrical-engineering, structural-engineering, steel, welding

How much steam is emitted from an electric arc furnace in a unit of time? I have not been able to find any data on this which is strange considering the amount of water that is used to cool an electric arc furnace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I‘m not quite sure i understand the question, assuming everything is fine, there should be no steam at all. These kind of systems can violently explode if there is a runaway steam production...as quoted [here](https://spraycooled.tsg.bz/wp-content/uploads/EAF-Explosions-A-Deadly-but-Preventable-Problem.pdf).
(Warning pdf)

Assuming a pressurized cooling system:

> ...A two-square-inch hole in a tubular panel results in more than 16,000 gallons of water spilled into the furnace in just one hour...

Using spray cooling, there is a loss of considerably less...only 5 gallons per hour.

Since water expands around 1700~x when turning to steam, one could calculate approx how much steam that would produce, assuming all of the water doesn‘t flash to stream at once and explode, but generally there shouldn‘t be any steam at all....or are you asking soemthing else?

Comment: Steam is made from electric arc furnaces due to the presence of a cooling tower that serves to cool all of the water used in the electric arc furnace.

Answer (score 1):

No steam at all from the furnace ; even the charge is preheated so that it is dry. Water may be used to cool the power transformers.

Comment: Steam is made due to a cooling tower being used to cool all of the water used in the electric arc furnace.

Comment: Unless it is a closed system ; like a fin-fan, air cools the water in tubes.